# Obtain page info for page with age restriction

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How do you obtain page info via the Graph API if the page is age restricted?

If the page is age restricted, requesting the page info returns no info about the page unless a valid access_token is provided, however Facebook appears not to accept an app access token as I get a 400 error when making the request.

Many Thanks,
Ady

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the access token for a user who's able to see the page; otherwise you'll get a n exception in the response

Comment: Thanks Igy, I already mention this in my question. I'm trying to obtain page information for a server side process using an app access token, not a logged in user.

Comment: Yes; this is not possible, you must use either the page access token or a user access token from someone who can access the page